# SQL Server: LIKE statement delivers wrong results with 'foo%'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-like

I have the problem that the `LIKE` statement `'foo%'` delivers less rows than the statement `'%foo%'`, although all rows are beginning with `foo`...

Here the example rows:

[image: Problem with LIKE Statement]

On the screenshot you can see, that the second result i.e. has rows like IEC60601-2-16ED2.. I already tried to detect white spaces before.

What can be the problem here?

Comment: Can you add `CAST(modul AS VARBINARY(30))` to the `SELECT` and show us the results of that?

Comment: Eventually some rows contains spaces? Try to trim space and filter it ... WHERE LTRIM(field) like 'foo%'

Comment: What happens if you add cur_identifier to the output?  You're limiting cur_identifer but showing modul... or is that some nuance of SQL$erver?

Comment: @Dennis - Good point. the where isn't against the column displayed. So the screenshot doesn't show anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you may have some special characters as the starting characters for some of the values

see what this returns

```
select len(modul) from table where col like '%foo%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Below format will get you results starting with the letter "IEC60601":

```
IEC60601%
```

also `%IEC60601%` will give you the result which contains that pattern.

Have a close look into your result. `%foo%` and `%foo` is not giving you the wrong result